# difference between Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy-Report-Only and Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy

Tags: html, http, http-headers

Hi i would like to know what is the difference between **Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy-Report-Only** and **Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The "report-only" variant doesn't enforce the header, it just reports it.

[Per](https://web.dev/coop-coep/):

> If you prefer to receive reports without blocking any embedded content or without isolating a popup window, append -Report-Only to respective headers: i.e. Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy-Report-Only and Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy-Report-Only